# MySql Inner Join from 2 tables loosing some rows

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a problem with queries and the whole logic of sql script.

My database has 2 tables. The first "travel" table has many unique trips with many columns. The second table "like" is the likes that exist for each trip as well as the name of the country to which the trip belongs

Now I want to `select * from trips order by likes where the country = "Greece".`

First of all I make the following code

```
SELECT T.*
FROM trips T INNER JOIN
     tripslikes L
     ON T.trip_id = L.trip_id
Where T.country_name = "Greece";
```

the results are all trips where the country = "Greece" this is repeated as many times as there are likes that have been made in this trip.

The problem is I'm loosing on my results the trips that doesn't have any like until now. The reason of this is because `ON T.trip_id = L.trip_id` <----- on this the trip_id from trips which have 0 likes doesn't exist on trip_id from likes and this is correct.

Any idea how can I get it the trips without any record on table likes (Meaning the trips whitout any record of like until now) ?

UPDATE1

```
select *, count(*) Total
from 
(
  SELECT T.*
FROM trips T
INNER JOIN tripslikes L
ON T.trip_id = L.trip_id Where T.country_name = "Greece"

) d
group by trip_id;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: try to replace INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN

Comment: Left Join will return not only trips to Greece but all the trips from all the countries.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no country in column in **trips** table then to find all the trips to **Greece** you must link this table to another table.
And if **tripslikes**  is the only one table with country column then I am afraid that there is no way to find all trips to Greece where there is no like for that trips.
Please try to find if there is any way to link a trip to a country other than the **tripslikes**  table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want trips to Greece with likes, you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM trips T
WHERE T.country_name = 'Greece' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tripslikes L
              WHERE T.trip_id = L.trip_id
             );
```

This removes the duplicates.  If you want trips with no likes, then switch to `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM trips T
WHERE T.country_name = 'Greece' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tripslikes L
                  WHERE T.trip_id = L.trip_id
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using this code ----> (See the UPDATE 1 ON QUESTION) and I'm getting 3 rows instead of 4, that is my problem.. how to get the fourth row with total 0. Have any idea ?

Comment: @ΠέτροςΠολλάκης . . . I think this answers your original question.  If you have a different question, then provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want.